# AWS iOS SDK 1.5.0 copyObject causes crash with memory error

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

IOS 5+;
ARC Enabled;
aws-ios-sdk 1.5.0

I am trying to copy files from one "folder" to "another" in Amazon S3. I can see on Amazon S3 files has been successfully copied but afterward my app crashes with memory error

I can see `copyObject` is deprecated but I have to copy files so I use it and get following error when I enable zombies;

**-S3CopyObjectResponse release: message sent to deallocated instance**

```
//copy request
            S3CopyObjectRequest *copyToNewFolder=[[S3CopyObjectRequest alloc] initWithSourceKey:amazonFileName sourceBucket:[Constants userEventBucket] destinationKey:destinationFile destinationBucket:[Constants userEventBucket]];
                 copyToNewFolder.metadataDirective = @"COPY";

            S3CopyObjectResponse *copiedResponse=[self.s3 copyObject:copyToNewFolder];
            if(copiedResponse.error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", copiedResponse.error);
                return;
            }
```

How can I copy files without getting memory error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem arising from the bad choice of method naming in AWS SDK. Note that the AWS SDK doesn't support ARC.

```
[self.s3 copyObject:copyToNewFolder];
```

When ARC sees this method name, it assumes that the method returns a value with outstanding retain count according to Obj-C naming conventions. `Methods in the alloc, copy, init, mutableCopy, and new families are implicitly marked __attribute__((ns_returns_retained))` ([Source](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values)). But, surprise surprise, this `copyObject` method returns an autoreleased instance (See [AmazonS3Client.m:474](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/src/Amazon.S3/AmazonS3Client.m#L474) and [AmazonS3Client.m:578](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/src/Amazon.S3/AmazonS3Client.m#L578)) since AWS is using `copy` in a different context here. The result? An over-released object and the crash.

The solution is to mark the method explicitly with `__attribute__((ns_returns_not_retained))` or `NS_RETURNS_NON_RETAINED`. I see that Amazon has already deprecated this method (perhaps to rectify the problem you're facing), so you can simply use `objectCopy` method instead.

Further reading: [1](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095855/how-arc-works-when-using-third-library-code)